# COUNT по условию

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT
    r.id_nomenclature, 
    n.name AS "name_nomenclature",  
    COUNT(n.name) OVER (PARTITION BY rg.id_rsd_group) AS "count_nomenclature", 
    rg.id_rsd_group AS "id_group", 
    r.id AS "id_expend"
FROM rsd AS r 
LEFT JOIN rsd_group AS rg ON rg.id_rsd = r.id 
LEFT JOIN nomenclature AS n ON n.id = r.id_nomenclature
GROUP BY
    r.id_nomenclature, n.name, n.id, rg.id_rsd_group, r.id
ORDER BY 
    rg.id_rsd_group DESC;
```

вот его вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне надо записывать в count_nomenclature количество одинаковых name_nomenclature находящихся в одной и той же группе id_group. но этот запрос считает количество всех name_nomenclature в группе id_group, несмотря что там написано COUNT(n.name).

получается что написанное COUNT(n.name) равноценно COUNT(*), так же не должно быть.

СУБД postgree. Как исправить?

Comment: А OVER-то тут зачем? просто COUNT(n.name) недостаточно?

Comment: @Akina ну и будут там одни единицы.

Comment: А что Вы хотели? непонятно... получить при одной группировке (`GROUP BY r.id_nomenclature, n.name, n.id, rg.id_rsd_group, r.id`) данные для другой группировки (`GROUP BY n.name`)? Кстати, а зачем группировка ещё и по n.id?

Comment: @Mike дали правильный ответ

Comment: @perfect Да, я уже вижу. в следующий раз постарайтесь более точно формулировать вопрос. Лучше всего помимо получившихся данных давать еще образец того, что должно получится, по нему гораздо быстрее и точнее можно догадаться, что нужно :)

Comment: @Mike я курить бросаю. голова не думает сегодня. извини

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`COUNT(n.name)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) считает количество строк по которым `n.name` не равно NULL.

Вам нужно количество строк с таким же `name` и `id_group`? Если да, то попробуйте так:

```
COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY rg.id_rsd_group, n.name) AS "count_nomenclature",
```

Comment: да это то что нужно, большое вам спасибо.